# Getting "System.Security.SecurityException" while calling a web api from RDL

Tags: c#, api, web

I need to call a web API from RDL file which is present in the reporting project hosted in SSRS. There is one field in the RDL report which will consume a Web Api response. I have written code in RDL to call that api and get the response using System.net Library but it is getting failed due to some System.Web.permission error.

I have tried to consume the web api using below code written in VB.NET (Target framework version 2.0).I also tried to set `trustlevel = full` in *web.config* but that doesn't work and still getting permission denied error.
I am getting successful web api response on executing the same code with `httpWebRequest`..etc from console application, but it fails when I try to call from RDL.
 Please let me know how to fix the System.net library permission error.

Getting below error while invoking the above function to consume web api response:

```
System.Security.SecurityException: Request for the permission of type 'System.Net.WebPermission, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed.
at System.Security.CodeAccessSecurityEngine.Check(Object demand, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean isPermSet)
at System.Security.CodeAccessPermission.Demand()
```

Code:

```
`Public Function STSCall() As String
    Dim url As String = "https://httpbin.org/get?token=8041637103881119"
    Dim cardNumber As String = String.Empty
    Dim httpWebRequest = CType(System.Net.WebRequest.Create(url), System.Net.HttpWebRequest)
    httpWebRequest.Method = "GET"
    httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json"
    httpWebRequest.Headers.Add("X-AuthMode", "ServerSimpleAuth")
    httpWebRequest.Headers.Add("X-ServerAuthKey", "STS")
    Dim response = CType(httpWebRequest.GetResponse(), System.Net.HttpWebResponse)

    Dim StreamReader As New System.IO.StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), System.Text.Encoding.ASCII)
    cardNumber = StreamReader.ToString()

    Return cardNumber
    End Function`
```

Comment: How are you running/testing the RDL?
Is the Web Service API yours? I assume it is since you mention modifying the web.config

Comment: I haven't developed  that web api.  It's from another vendor.  I am just trying to consume it and the response of that needs to be implemented in RDL Reports. I have done changes in the <code> block of the. rdl file of that report where the field is tied to that logic where api is getting invoked. I am testing it on the SSRS server by uplaoding that rdl file.

Comment: What is the web.config that you are modifying. How are you testing in SSRS are you running it in the web reporting interface?

Comment: Welcome to SO. I advise you read the [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) article as it provides very useful information for newcomers on how to write questions. Quality questions help us provide you quality answers - Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your issue.

Comment: I tried to modify config file in the below path  C:\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS11.MSSQLSERVER\Reporting Services\ReportServer. I tested it using reporting services configuration manager.